# Adapter uses wrong layout when run in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I created a custom adapter and Im feeding it sample data to check if it's working probably ... the adapter have if else statement

```
if () {

else  if (){

}
```

yet it keeps running the code in the second condition even if the first if statement is true. "it displays only activity ids

**Sample Data**

```
public class ActivityListArray {

    public static ArrayList<Activity> getActivitiesList() {
    /* Activity (buildingnumber, acitivytname, activityid) */
        final ArrayList<Activity> soleyaactivities = new ArrayList<Activity>();
        activities.add(new Activity("E1", "(BS-C-E1) Backfilling Up To SOG", "A9360"));
        activities.add(new Activity("D1", "(BS-C-D1) Insulation for P.C SOG", "A10320"));

        return activities;
    }
}
```

**Adapter code**

```
public class ActivityAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Activity> {

    public Activity currentActivity;
    public String BuildingNumber;
    public String currentbuildingnumber;

    public ActivityAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Activity> Activities, String adapterbuildingnumber) {
        super(context, 0, Activities);
        // This is the Building number of the Clicked Building
        currentbuildingnumber = adapterbuildingnumber;
        // This is the Building number of the Activity
        BuildingNumber = currentActivity.getBuildingNumber();
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;

        if (BuildingNumber.equals(currentbuildingnumber)) {

            // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
            if (v == null) {
                v = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.project_actvitiy_list, parent, false);
            }

            // Get the {@link Word} object located at this position in the list
            currentActivity = getItem(position);

            TextView Act_ID = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.emptyslot);
            TextView Act_Name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.Act_Name);

            Act_ID.setText(String.valueOf(currentActivity.getActivityID()));
        Act_Name.setText(String.valueOf(currentActivity.getActivityName()));
        }

        }

        else  if (BuildingNumber != currentbuildingnumber){


            // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
            if (v == null) {
                v = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.project_actvitiy_list_empty, parent, false);
            }

            // Get the {@link Word} object located at this position in the list
            currentActivity = getItem(position);

            TextView Act_ID = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.emptyslot);

            Act_ID.setText(String.valueOf(currentActivity.getActivityID()));
        }

        return v;
    }
    }
```

**project_actvitiy_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/backgroundColor"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".SoleyaProjectSchedule">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Act_ID"
                style="@style/ProjectUpdate_Activity"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:text="TextView" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Name"
                style="@style/ProjectUpdate_Activity"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="8"
                android:textColor="@color/blue"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="Activity Name" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**project_actvitiy_list_empty.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:background="@color/backgroundColor"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".SoleyaProjectSchedule">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/emptyslot"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: final ArrayList<Activity> soleyaactivities = new ArrayList<Activity>();  you are create an arraylist object soleyaactivities but you use activities.add to add items in arraylist what is activities?

Comment: @ShivamKumar custom object class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check if this statement returns true:

```
if (BuildingNumber.equals(currentbuildingnumber))
```

Maybe it returns false.

Comment: It does, that's why I have else if statement to handle the execution of false

Comment: @Mustafa Maybe it returns false for any case. In your else if you set only one value instead of two. And try to delete             if (v == null) {
                v = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.project_actvitiy_list_empty, parent, false);
            } and set instead    v = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.project_actvitiy_list_empty, parent, false); I cannot see sense in this check.

Comment: edited however same problem remains ... it keeps using the "project_actvitiy_list_empty.xml" for true and false statements